# How can I control the alignment of y axes in multiple subplots with pyqtgraph when the tick labels have different lengths?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, pyqtgraph

I am using pyqtgraph to make a plot with a few subplots and shared X axes. However, when the tick labels have different lengths, the Y axes do not line up with each other. How can I make the plots line up properly, despite differences in the size of tick labels or axis labels?

```
from pyqtgraph import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

# Make up some data ----------
x = np.linspace(0, 80, 81)
y1 = np.sqrt(x)
y2 = 10*x**2

# Set up the plot ----------
# Switch to using white background and black foreground
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
pw = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="plot test")
gv = pw
layout_ = pg.GraphicsLayout()
gv.setCentralItem(layout_)
gv.show()
layout = layout_.addLayout(colspan=1)
layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
# Top row: title
layout.addLabel('title', colspan=2)
# Next row: main plot with y axis label
layout.nextRow()
layout.addLabel('y1', angle=-90, rowspan=1)
p1 = layout.addPlot()
# Next row: secondary plot
layout.nextRow()
layout.addLabel('y2', angle=-90, rowspan=1)
p2 = layout.addPlot()
# Bottom row: X axis label
layout.nextRow()
layout.addLabel("x", col=1, colspan=1)
# Share X axes
p2.setXLink(p1)

# Add data to plot ---------
p1.plot(x, y1, pen=pg.mkPen((255, 0, 0, 255), width=3))
p2.plot(x, y2, pen=pg.mkPen((0, 0, 255, 255), width=3))

# Start Qt event loop to keep the window open
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        app.exec_()  # Start QApplication event loop ***
```

[image: Output from example code]

Comment: `AxisItem` has `setWidth` and `setStyle` methods which might be helpful. http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/axisitem.html#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.setWidth

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyqtgraph import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys
# Make up some data ----------
x = np.linspace(0, 80, 81)
y1 = np.sqrt(x)
y2 = 10*x**2

# Set up the plot ----------
# Switch to using white background and black foreground
# pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
# pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
pw = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="plot test")
gv = pw
layout_ = pg.GraphicsLayout()
gv.setCentralItem(layout_)
gv.show()
layout = layout_.addLayout(colspan=1)
layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
# Top row: title
layout.addLabel('title', colspan=2)
# Next row: main plot with y axis label
layout.nextRow()
layout.addLabel('y1', angle=-90, rowspan=1)
p1 = layout.addPlot()
# Next row: secondary plot
layout.nextRow()
layout.addLabel('y2', angle=-90, rowspan=1)
p2 = layout.addPlot()
# Bottom row: X axis label
layout.nextRow()
layout.addLabel("x", col=1, colspan=1)
# Share X axes
p2.setXLink(p1)


p1.getAxis('left').setWidth(int(100))
p2.getAxis('left').setWidth(int(100))

# Add data to plot ---------
p1.plot(x, y1, pen=pg.mkPen((255, 0, 0, 255), width=3))
p2.plot(x, y2, pen=pg.mkPen((0, 0, 255, 255), width=3))

# Start Qt event loop to keep the window open
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        app.exec_()  # Start QApplication event loop ***
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is helpful if you provide some description to your code also

Comment: This technically works, but is there a way to make the widths lock together so they can change if needed if the plot is zoomed or something? This is manually setting a width of 100 which happens to work, but what if I didn't know that 100 was a good idea and I wanted it to be allowed to update automatically? I'm giving it +1 for being better than nothing but not accepting it yet because I hope for more.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, the key to this solution is the added `p1.getAxis('left').setWidth(int(100))` and `p2.getAxis('left').setWidth(int(100))`. Is forcing to int needed because the width is in pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Just link the 'left' axis to a view that is registered.
Something like:

```
Widths = [i.width() for i in xAxis]
maximum=Widths.index(max(Widths))
viewBox[maximum].register('largest')
for i in listPlots:
    i.getAxis('left').linkToView(viewBox[maximum])
```

where listPlots is the list of plotDataItems

Comment: I can't get this to work with the example.